# Firebase Realtimedatabase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do you prevent a user who logs into an app from uploading their details twice to a firebase realtime database? The user should only have one record in the database and be able to only update the existing record.

Comment: The record needs to have a unique key, in firebase you can use the unique firebase user id as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Use the User's key to point to a single object. 
Even though how many times they update the details in that key, it wouldn't create a duplicate record. Make use of the promises to handle the callback functionalities.